# Why isn't query plan changed when I enabled hashjoin?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm in PostgreSQL 9.2 and tried to change query plan manually as follows in `pgadmin`:

```
SET enable_hashjoin TO true;
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT *
FROM tbl1 
FULL OUTER JOIN tbl2 ON SOME_CONDITION
FULL OUTER JOIN tbl3 ON SOME_CONDITION
OFFSET 2000 LIMIT 20
```

And the result was completely the same as it would be:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT *
FROM tbl1 
FULL OUTER JOIN tbl2 ON SOME_CONDITION
FULL OUTER JOIN tbl3 ON SOME_CONDITION
OFFSET 2000 LIMIT 20
```

The result:

```
"  ->  Merge Full Join  (cost=899265.88..980151.59 rows=441998 width=127) (actual time=11985.047..11993.662 rows=2020 loops=1)"
"        Merge Cond: ((daily_profit.currency_id = players_external_transactions.currency_id) AND (daily_profit.platform_id = players_external_transactions.platform_id) AND (daily_profit.partner_id = players_external_transactions.partner_id) AND (daily_profit.player_id = players_external_transactions.player_id))"
"        ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=816428.39..888252.93 rows=441998 width=21) (actual time=10413.132..10420.008 rows=1611 loops=1)"
"              Group Key: daily_profit.currency_id, daily_profit.platform_id, daily_profit.partner_id, daily_profit.player_id"
"              ->  Sort  (cost=816428.39..827478.32 rows=4419971 width=21) (actual time=10413.121..10416.994 rows=8380 loops=1)"
"                    Sort Key: daily_profit.currency_id, daily_profit.platform_id, daily_profit.partner_id, daily_profit.player_id"
"                    Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 134104kB"
"                    ->  Seq Scan on daily_profit  (cost=0.00..147267.71 rows=4419971 width=21) (actual time=0.019..1148.922 rows=4415703 loops=1)"
```

As you can see, we have merge full join here. But I expected something like hash join to be in the plan. What did I do wrong?

Comment: It seems you don't have statistics (observed and predicted rowcounts differ too much). I suggest you first run `VACUUM ANALYZE` on the tables.

Comment: It is enabled by default so that doesn't change anything.

Comment: @JakubKania So, how can I change it to sort-merge join?

Comment: The optimizer *could* use indexes, if there *were* indexes supporting the joined or restricted fields, *if* the statistics *would* suggest this kind of plan.